# TranslateAnimation of an half hidden view

Tags: android, android-listview

During a TranslateAnimation I'm trying to move a view from outside the window to the inside.

In a suggestion they say to use a ScrollView but even with it there is no change at all.

Any other way to accomplish that?

EDIT

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_linear_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background_box" >

    <com.project.view.PullToRefreshListView
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainList"
        android:background="@color/background_list"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/element_contacts_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the animation

```
private void bounceBackHeader(){
    int yTranslate = state == State.REFRESHING ?
            header.getHeight() - headerContainer.getHeight() :
            -headerContainer.getHeight() - headerContainer.getTop() + getPaddingTop();

    TranslateAnimation bounceAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, yTranslate);

    bounceAnimation.setDuration(BOUNCE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    bounceAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
    bounceAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
    bounceAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
    bounceAnimation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(BOUNCE_OVERSHOOT_TENSION));
    bounceAnimation.setAnimationListener(new HeaderAnimationListener(yTranslate));

    startAnimation(bounceAnimation);
}
```

The problem occurs when I drag the listview items of.. it animates only the remaining part of the view and not the whole view.

Comment: if you post .gif image or explain in details it would be better.

Comment: edited the intro.. better now? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that when I was moving the view outside the parentView, the view is cut.

The solution was to add this option to the parentView:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

In this way, the parentView won't cut the childView, and in the translation from outside to the inside, the view will still be complete as before.